# Qt Regular Expression (?: [Ff]eat[.]? )|(?: [[Ff]eaturing][.]?)

Tags: regex, qt

In a Qt project I'm having to split a QString by the following separators

1. Feat.
2. feat.
3. Feat
4. feat
5. Featuring
6. featuring.
7. Featuring
8. featuring

My best try was `(?: [Ff]eat[.]? )|(?: [[Ff]eaturing][.]?)` as in

```
QRegExp xp("(?: [Ff]eat[.]? )|(?: [[Ff]eaturing][.]? )");
QString str = "Eminem Feat. Rihanna";
QStringList list = alist.split(xp);
```

The above lines of codes doesn't work for me. This is a simple RegExp problem. I'm just too confused. Any sort of help or suggestion would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra character class in the 2nd part of regex.

Try using this:

```
QRegExp xp("(?: [Ff]eat[.]? )|(?: [Ff]eaturing[.]? )");
```

And you can combine both of them in one pattern, using `?` quantifier, and you don't need the outermost non-capturing group.

```
QRegExp xp(" [Ff]eat(?:uring)?[.]? ");
```

Comment: If you want to capture all case situations (e.g., FEAT, FEat, and feat), you might consider using [QRegExp::setCaseSensitivity()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qregexp.html#setCaseSensitivity). That would be much simpler than manually entering every letter individually like you do with `[Ff]`.

Comment: @Phlucious :That makes sense. But any idea how to check for ft. or Ft. aswell?

Comment: `QRegExp xp("\\sf(?:ea)?t(?:uring)?[.]?\\s");` is how I would do it. The main difference is that you wrap the "ea" to make it optional. If you used Rohit's first option, then you simply add it as another OR option like in `QRegExp xp("(?:\\sfeat[.]?\\s)|(?:\\sfeaturing[.]?\\s)|(?:\\sft[.]?\\s)");` Play with it in Qt's regular expressions example.

Comment: I've tried on `QRegExp xp("\\sf(?:ea)?t(?:uring)?[.]?\\s")` but it matches **fturing** too! Anyways I'll figure it out and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
(?: [fF]eat(?:uring)?\.? )
```

Or replace the spaces with word boundaries

```
(?:\b[fF]eat(?:uring)?\.?\b)
```